# How to count the number of times a value is in a column based on particular row values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

```
     Outlook     Temperature    PlayTennis   Value

0     Sunny           60           Yes         1

1     Sunny           70           Yes         1

2     Sunny           40            No         1

3  Overcast           40            No         1

4  Overcast           60           Yes         1

5  Overcast           50           Yes         1

6  Overcast           70           Yes         1

7  Overcast           80           Yes         1

8      Rain           65            No         1

9      Rain           70           Yes         1
```

and I want to get this

```
Outlook    Yes    No

Sunny       2      1

Overcast    4      1

Rain        1      1
```

Not sure what commands to use to count the yesses and nos based on Sunny/Overcast/Rain

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is generally expected here that you either show code you've written or describe research you've done to try to solve your problem. As your question is currently written, it sounds like a request for code. Have you made any attempts you can share with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this?

```
df.groupby('Outlook').apply(lambda g: g['PlayTennis'].value_counts())
```

or, for your exact spec:

```
df.groupby('Outlook').apply(lambda g: g['PlayTennis'].value_counts()).unstack(1)
```

or even shorter:

```
df.groupby('Outlook')['PlayTennis'].value_counts().unstack(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to start out with:

```
forecasts = [
    ["sunny", "yes"],
    ["sunny", "yes"],
    ["sunny", "no"],
    ["overcast", "no"],
    # more forecasts ...
]
myForecasts = {}
for forecast in forecasts:
    if forecast[0] not in myForecasts:
        myForecasts[forecast[0]] = [0, 0]

    if forecast[1] == "yes":
        myForecasts[forecast[0]][0] += 1

    else:
        myForecasts[forecast[0]][1] += 1

print("Outlook | Yes | No")
for myForecast in myForecasts:
    print("{} | {} | {}".format(myForecast, myForecasts[myForecast][0], myForecasts[myForecast][1]))
```

I hope this helps some.  And next time, please show us that you've done your homework.

Comment: Could you help me do this with Pandas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with Pandas; what exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pd.pivot_table` to solve this

```
In [88]: pd.pivot_table(df, index='Outlook', cols='PlayTennis',
                         values='Value', aggfunc='sum') 
Out[88]:
PlayTennis  No  Yes
Outlook
Overcast     1    4
Rain         1    1
Sunny        1    2
```

Also, You can `groupby` your data on `'Outlook', 'PlayTennis'` get the count and use `unstack('PlayTennis')`

```
In [87]: df.groupby(['Outlook', 'PlayTennis']).size().unstack('PlayTennis')
Out[87]:
PlayTennis  No  Yes
Outlook
Overcast     1    4
Rain         1    1
Sunny        1    2
```